# Angular2 with primeng components Nativescript issues

Tags: node.js, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, primeng

I could able to work on quickstart groceries app from nativescript page. In the login page I have replaced the  Angular2 button to primeng button. While convert/transpile the code through TNS command it throws an error on primeng/button.js line no 109,47 as Variable Event cannot be referenced.

Comment: Does primeng have native android and iOS components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PrimeNG** is a set of UI components made for the web and they do not have logic that can convert them to native Android and/or iOS components. So in two words - you can not use PrimeNG in NativeScript directly.

Comment: Does this still apply?  I am interested in using PrimeVue with Nativescript-vue.  Being new to UI development, I was sure if it was possible.